# Skimr - cant seem to produce the histograms

Tags: r, histogram, summary, skimr

came across this seemingly new package - skimr, which looks pretty nifty, and was trying it out and looks like I'm missing some package installation. Skim works fine except that it doesn't print the histogram, it is supposed to print for numeric variables. I am merely trying the examples given in the documentation.

Link to skimr documentation here - https://github.com/ropenscilabs/skimr#skimr

this is the code I'm using

```
    devtools::install_github("hadley/colformat")
    devtools::install_github("ropenscilabs/skimr")
    library(skimr)
    a<-skim(mtcars)
    dim(a)
    View(a)
```

instead of histograms being printed, I see some ASCII/unicode characters [image].

Comment: Looks like a bug in the package where it doesn't work well on Windows: https://github.com/ropenscilabs/skimr/issues/54

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution that can be used to workaround the above problem is to set the locale of the R system to `Chinese` and to set the font of the R console to `NSimSun`.

```
temp <- tempfile()
cat("font = NSimSun\n", file = temp, append = TRUE)
loadRconsole(file = temp)
Sys.setlocale( locale='Chinese' )

library(skimr)
(a <- skim(mtcars))
```

[image]

```
View(a)
```

[image]

In RStudio this solution works only partially. Histograms generated by `skim` can be visualized only using `View` after setting the locale of R to `Chinese`

```
Sys.setlocale( locale='Chinese' )
library(skimr)
a <- skim(mtcars)
View(a)
```

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Can you give a hint on the potential side effects of changing the language?

Comment: Please, find the last chunk of code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51340323/4783029). In that case, changing the locale resulted in an error.